# How to delete a word from an array if you got it 3 times in a row?

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm doing my quiz app. I got a structured array that contains words, their translations, definitions, etc. After every answer, my app generates a random question. So, my question is how to delete a word from my array if user got it right for 3 times in a row.

**How do I attach a counter to correctly answered word (that will be counting right answers for every single word in the array)?**

I tried to triple my array and then delete this word, but it's a lot of coding and repetitive lines.

Comment: jus have an int variable in your model class. After each successful answer increment that variable. once the count reaches 3 then delete that particular word from an array

Comment: @Gyanendra thank you for the solution, seems to be working.

Comment: From a UX-perspective, you might want to consider counting the number of subsequent correct answers (i.e. resetting the counter for a faulty answer) or the CUMSUM+ over the answers (correct answer increases the sum by 1, whereas an incorrect decreases it but 1, however never below 0). Otherwise the user could eventually run out of questions even with a correct answer ration of a very low percentage for each removed question (i.e., pure guesses, no learning!).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class to get the next question and update the array after a question has been answered correctly:

```
class QuestionProvider {
    struct Question {
        let question: String
        let answer: String
        var rightAnswers: Int

        init(question: String, answer: String) {
            self.question = question
            self.answer = answer
            self.rightAnswers = 0
        }
    }
    private var questions = [Question]()

    func add(question: Question) {
        questions.append(question)
    }

    func getNextQuestion() -> Question {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questions.count)))
        return questions[index]
    }

    func answeredCorrectly(question: Question) {
        guard let index = questions.index(where: {$0.question == question.question}) else { return }
        var qa = questions[index]
        qa.rightAnswers += 1
        if qa.rightAnswers >= 3 {
            questions.remove(at: index)
        } else {
            questions[index] = qa
        }
    }
}
```